# How I can refresh the view when HttpConnect?

Tags: android, http, view, refresh

Receive information from the network and attach that data to the view.

Use Ion library,

```
private void getListInfo() {

    Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load("POST", "URL..")
            .setBodyParameter("Parameters", "Parameters")
            .asString()
            .withResponse()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<String> result) {

                    if (e != null) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } else {

                        int resultCode = result.getHeaders().code();
                        String resultInfo = result.getResult();

                        if (resultCode == 200) {

                            Log.d("EntrantInfo", resultInfo);

                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            Type type = new TypeToken<List<Data>>() {
                            }.getType();

                            listItems = gson.fromJson(resultInfo, type);
                            Adapter.setItems(listItems);
                            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            textview.setText(data);

                        }

                    }

                }
            });

}
```

So, I call the `getListInfo()` method at `onCreate()`.

I move that 'A' activity, I can't see the data at all.

In recyclerview or listview, use `notifyDataSetChanged()` but I can't see the list.

But, when I move back and move 'A' activity again, I can see the data and view.

So I think I have got information, but it did not update in that view.

Now, how I can see the view when I get the information from server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SwipeRefreshLayout to refresh your data on swipe :
[SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface)

Add the data loading function to the `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener`

Or

You can set a TimerTask to refresh your data

```
TimerTask timerTask;
Timer timer;
timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //load your data
                    getListInfo();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 200);
```

And make sure to cancel the timer `onPause()`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but when I load lots of information or big size file, this solution will not nice suggestion because of reload.

Comment: You can stop the timer before you start getting data using `timer.cancel()` and start the timer again using `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 200);` after the data is fully loaded.